# live web server for seeing raspberry pi 3 camera

Tags: camera, web-server

I have tried looking through some tutorials, but I can't find one that puts ALL the pieces together for what I am trying to accomplish, and explaining it in a crystal clear way for a noob. Here's what I'd like to do:

I want to have a raspberry pi 3 with a camera attached interfacing with some kind of web server that I can access across the internet. I want to be able to see the camera feed (of my house) from my phone or a hotel WiFi when I'm traveling in another state and such. Frame rate is not super important, I would be happy getting even 1 frame per second. It would be nice to have a little bit of security like a password login or something, but that's optional.

I have never done any kind of web services that are live to the internet, and I'm not sure what hardware/services I need to get. I'm assuming I have to pay for some web service to make it live, but again, I'm not sure. Do I need a more powerful PC running and interfacing with the RP3, or can the RP3 handle everything?

The tutorials I have found seem to list the steps to get a web server on a LAN, or the details on how to get it live were a bit underexplained.

Comment: You could use motioneyeos https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki to serve the camera image this would allow you to view the image from anywhere on your LAN. To be able to access it from anywhere you will need to forward a port on your router and either configure dynamic DNS or obtain a static IP. Forwarding a port and configuring DNS is off-topic for this site.